# PostGIS geometry support

Tags: postgis

Can postgis for postgresql support complex geometric types like spheroids?

Answer (score 3):

PostGIS supports spheroids defined in [WKT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text).

For an example, this [page's section on ST_length_spheroid](http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.3/ch06.html#id2577672) shows how the spheroid is defined, as well as using a sample.

As for other complex types - PostGIS supports pretty much all of the GEOS geometry types natively.

Answer (score 1):

There is some functions in postgis that takes a spehorid as an input and I'm pretty sure that you can define your own (  spheroid (or ellipsoid))
http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.3/ch06.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does support Spheroids, and in general PostGIS has much fuller capabilities than the similar offering for MySQL. I use PostGIS for this: www.trailbehind.com.

The PostGIS documentation sucks though.